# When deploying across VMs in Azure are they distributed across multiple data centers

Tags: azure

We see US-West when deploying VMs. does that mean that US-West spans across multiple data centers or is it just one datacenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy to a region you are deploying to a single data center location. In reality each region is likely multiple buildings on a large site, but you can treat it as a single location.